# Centos 5.2 x86_64 install mod_wsgi.so error undefined symbol: ap_close_listeners

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, installation, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi.so on my VPS runninr Centors 5.21.
I installed python 2.6 and compiled mod_wsgi. It all worked with ought an error.
When i include the mod_wsgi.so in Apache i get the error:

```
mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: ap_close_listeners ---
```

I searched google with no luck. Any ideas?
Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_wsgi.so was compiled against a more recent version of Apache develelopment package than the version of Apache you are deploying to. Ensure that the core Apache package and development package version that you are compiling against are for the same version of Apache and you should be fine. Also ensure you are using most recent mod_wsgi version.

Comment: it was compiled on the same machine as the apache. i tried the latest mod_wsgi

Comment: But are the apache core and dev packages you have installed the same version? Linux distributions split the two. The core package contains the Apache binary and the dev package the header files. The versions of each package need to be the same. Ensure you do an update of the core package to pick up latest in case it is an older version that doesn't have the ap_close_listeners() function as part of it.

Comment: Specifically, the ap_close_listeners() function only became part of Apache back in 2005-11-15. So a very long time ago. The Apache header files you are compiling against though are for a version of Apache newer than that date.

Comment: how can i check the apache core and dev? I know the apache running on this machine is 2.0.63

Comment: upgraded to apache2.2 and it seem to work